# Knockout.js computed

Tags: javascript, html, knockout.js

I am using Knockout.js to develop a calculator. I am facing a situation that I don't know how to handle.
In the below example, everything works fine when the user enters a product and value and the values are saved in the DB. But when the user comes to edit this page, my requirement is to show all the values the user entered along with the total. But when the user changes something in the product or quantity, the total should change as expected.

We now store the total in DB and total could be changed by some admin users.In this case,is there a way we can override the computed value when the user goes to the edit page but when the user changes product or quantity,then the compute should happen with the latest values from product and quantity.

Help is appreciated.

```
var TsFoundationDeviceModel = function(product,qty) {
var self = this;
self.product = ko.observable();
self.quantity= ko.observable();
self.computedExample = ko.computed(function() {
   return self.product() * self.quantity() ;
});}
```

My HTML code looks like

```
<input name="product" data-bind="value:product">
<input name="value" data-bind="value:value">
<input name="total" data-bind="value:computedExample"/>
```

Comment: When you load the edit page, can you use javascript or jQuery to assign the total? Then when you make changes, the normal AppViewModel() will update the total as needed?

Comment: But my model will array of values ,may be 20 ..doing with script would be tough.

Comment: Did you find any solution for this? I am also struggling with the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

You have to bind the view to the screen. Check out this fiddle and give it

```
 var TsFoundationDeviceModel = function(product,qty) {
var self = this;
self.product = ko.observable(product);
self.quantity= ko.observable(qty);
self.computedExample = ko.computed(function() {
 return self.product() * self.quantity() ;
});}

ko.applyBindings(new TsFoundationDeviceModel(2,3));
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Z6VPV/5/

Comment: Is there a way I can just show the computed value straight from the DB.Sometimes the computed value changes in the DB from a third party.

Comment: you would have to setup a reoccurring ajax call that refreshes the object.

Comment: is there is a way I can override the computed value with the value that I get from the DB.

Answer (score 0):

When you reference observables within your computed you need to treat them like functions so instead of `return self.product * self.quantity ;` you would use `return self.product() * self.quantity();`

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/SAV9A/

Comment: Oops.The code is edited now.but in this case,I want to show the data coming from DB when the user comes to edit page.Sometimes the total in DB changes by a third party API.

Comment: You'll need to write an ajax call to fetch the data from the database, and store that value in your observable. If there are points in your code where you think the data may be stale (changed in the db via api) you would refresh the data by the same ajax method you used to fetch the value to initialize.

Comment: is there is a way I can override the computed value with the value that I get from the DB.